# Keras says my cuda drivers are incompatibile, but they are in fact compatibile versions

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I ran a simple keras script that trains a conv net on the MNIST database. This script works on my laptop yet not on my PC with the GeForce RTX 2070 graphics card.

The error is this:

```
  File "/home/squall/spencer/kaggle/understanding_cloud_organization/mnist_model.py", line 67, in <module>
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
  File "/home/squall/anaconda3/envs/thunder/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1239, in fit
    validation_freq=validation_freq)
  File "/home/squall/anaconda3/envs/thunder/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 196, in fit_loop
    outs = fit_function(ins_batch)
  File "/home/squall/anaconda3/envs/thunder/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3292, in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File "/home/squall/anaconda3/envs/thunder/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1458, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}}]]
     [[metrics/accuracy/Identity/_91]]
  (1) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

Cuda is 10.1. Driver is 418.56. CuDNN is 7.4.2. Tensorflow is 1.14. According to the official Nvidia chart, these are all compatible versions.

Any ideas?

Comment: both versions don't match,please check Nvidia web site

Answer (score 0):

Try this
[image]

[image]

PS: CUDA is 10.0 and cuDNN is 7.6.3 for CUDA10.0

Answer (score 0):

For tensorflow to work, you need Cuda 10 version. Uninstall the Cuda 10.1 completely and install supported Cuda 10. You can read about requirements for TF [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements).